# Destructor for char arrays Error

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class Class 
{
private:
    char* str;
public:
    Class(const char* src) 
    {
        str = new char[strlen(src)];
        strcpy(str,source);
    }
    ~Class() {
        delete [] str;
    }
};
```

A main function calls the constructor with some string. Upon exiting, the runtime crashes on the destructor.The error message is:

```
pointer being freed was not allocated
```

How can I solve this

Comment: Your destructor should be called `~Class()`. Also, do you really want to use a `char*` over an `std::string` or an `std::vector<char>` or a C++11 `std::array` (depending on your use case, which `string` fits here).

Comment: It looks to me like the error message was truncated a little. Also, you're not allocating enough memory for the string (you need to allocate strlen(src) + 1).

Comment: If you changed your destructor to `~Classs` instead of `~Test`, it is very easy to make your `Class` fall flat on its face. `int main() { Class c1("a"); Class c2(c1); }`  There, I just made your `Class` do bad things when `main` returns.

Comment: I can not see why the prog should crash with a single Class (or Test) object, if you change strlen(src) to strlen(src)+1, as Timo said. But heed @PaulMcKenzie's advice. Try to understand it.

Comment: I made a typo. The destructor is effectively ~Class and I get the error with it (error reported is truncated a little...)

Answer (score 4):

Just look how nicer and safer your code becomes with use of `std::string`:

```
class Class {
    std::string str;
public:
    Class(char const *src) : str(src) {}
};
```

And you don't need to worry about deleting memory, about allocating +1 character space for the `\0` character at the end etc.

Answer (score 0):

The copy constructor should like this.

```
Class(const char* src) 
{
    str = new char[strlen(src) + 1];// +1 is missed in original code.
    strcpy(str,source); // copy and append '\0'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you must check a pointer to NULL , if os cant allocate smemory to array of char str . str being NULL, delete[] null pointer - problem.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
class Class 
{
    private:
    char* str;
    public:
    Class(const char* src) 
    {
        str = new char[strlen(src)];
        if(str) {
            strcpy(str,src);
        }
    }
    char* getstr() { return str; }
    ~Class() {
        if(str) {
            delete [] str;
        }    
    }
};
int main() {
    Class te("sdfs\n");
    printf("%s",te.getstr());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) You didn't allocate enough room for the string. 2) There is no need to check for NULL when issuing a `delete`. 3) The `Class` still suffers from copying and assignment issues. 4) operator `new` (without the `nothrow`) does not return NULL if it fails (at least not on a conforming compiler)